# How to add a prefix "91" to a textbox using Jquery or HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jquery, i have a form. In that i am trying to add prefix `91` to mobile number field. I tried so many ways but not working.

```js
$('#mobile').keyup(function() {
  var oldvalue = $(this).val();
  var field = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (field.value.indexOf('91') !== 0) {
      $(field).val(oldvalue);
    }
  }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ifsc" class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> IFSC </label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ifsc" name="ifsc" maxlength="8" placeholder="Enter ifsc" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> Accounts</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="account" id="account" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Account No" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="mobile" class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> MOBILE NO</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" data-minlength="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Why are you mixing vanilla js and jquery? `.val() vs value`

Comment: @Darren Sweeney: I searched in google, i don't know that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below (explained through comments).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mobile').keyup(function() {//use mouseout
    if($(this).val().indexOf('9') == 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).val());
    }else{
      $(this).val("91" + $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ifsc" class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> IFSC </label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ifsc"  name="ifsc"  maxlength="8" placeholder="Enter ifsc"/>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> Accounts</label>
              <div class="col-md-6" > 
    <input type="text" name="account" id= "account" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Account No"/>
              </div>
           </div>                           
         <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="mobile" class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> MOBILE NO</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile"  data-minlength="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter Contact Number"/>
        </div>                        
        </div> 

  </div>
</form>
```

Note:-

Add jQuery library before adding jQuery code.

Don't mix java-script/jQuery syntaxes with each-other.Use either one purely.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mobile').keyup(function() {  
            var oldvalue=$(this).val();
            var field=this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if(field.value.indexOf('91') !== 0) {
                    $(field).val("91"+oldvalue);
                } 
            }, 1);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mobile').keyup(function() {         
            var oldvalue=$(this).val();
            var field=this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if(field.value.indexOf('91') !== 0) {
                    $(field).val("91" +oldvalue);
                } 
            }, 1);
        });
    });
```

I just modified your code but there are many other options available for this

Answer (score 1):

Use on **focus event of jQuery** like this

```
 $('#phone').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val().substring(0,3) !== '+61'){
        $(this).val("+61" + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

On focus, it pre-fills the input field with country code.